# a closed projection on a C*-algebra is compact iff it is closed on the multiplier algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

I'm trying to understand the proof for the equivalence of (i) and (v) in the following picture. I don't quite understand what the highlighted sentence means. I want to know why there is a surjection from $B$ onto $M(A)/A$. Can anyone explain for me, or provide some other proof? Thanks in advance.

[image: closed-compact]

The picture can be found in the following paper:

*Brown, Lawrence G.*, [**Semicontinuity and multipliers of (C^*)-algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1988-038-5), Can. J. Math. 40, No. 4, 865-988 (1988). [ZBL0647.46044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0647.46044).  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qap7e.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3UGY.png